# Unable to load shared library 'libSkiaSharp' or one of its dependencies on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, .net-6.0, skiasharp

I've built a .NET Core 6 application that runs without issue on my local Windows 11 machine. I've deployed it to an Ubuntu 20.04 server and I receive an error that it cannot load the libSkiaSharp shared library. I've seen other people report this issue but none of the suggestions are working for me.

**Error**

Error is received whenever SkiaSharp is used via code in a Linux environment
[image]

> Feb 9 19:40:10 vmi1190349 dotnet-MyTest[9456]:
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'SkiaSharp.SKData' threw an exception. <e LD_DEBUG environment
> variable: liblibSkiaSharp: cannot open shared object file: No such
> file or directory Feb 9 19:40:10 vmi1190349 dotnet-MyTest[9456]: fail:
> MyTest.Controllers.MyController[0] Feb 9 19:40:10 vmi1190349
> dotnet-MyTest[9456]: The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKData' threw
> an exception. Feb 9 19:40:10 vmi1190349 dotnet-MyTest[9456]:
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'SkiaSharp.SKData' threw an exception. Feb 9 19:40:10 vmi1190349
> dotnet-MyTest[9456]: ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load
> shared library 'libSkiaSharp' or one of its dependencies. In order to
> help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG
> environment variable: liblibSkiaSharp: cannot open shared object file:
> No such file or directory Feb 9 19:40:10 vmi1190349
> dotnet-MyTest[9456]: at SkiaSharp.SkiaApi.sk_data_new_empty() Feb 9
> 19:40:10 vmi1190349 dotnet-MyTest[9456]: at SkiaSharp.SKData..cctor()
> Feb 9 19:40:10 vmi1190349 dotnet-MyTest[9456]: --- End of inner
> exception stack trace --- Feb 9 19:40:10 vmi1190349
> dotnet-MyTest[9456]: at SkiaSharp.SKData.Create(IntPtr address, Int32
> length) Feb 9 19:40:10 vmi1190349 dotnet-MyTest[9456]: at
> SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Decode(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer) Feb 9 19:40:10
> vmi1190349 dotnet-MyTest[9456]: at SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Decode(Byte[]
> buffer) Feb 9 19:40:10 vmi1190349 dotnet-MyTest[9456]: at
> Test.Common.Image.ImageManager.GenerateImage(ImageOptions MyPost,
> Details details) in
> C:\Users\TestUser\source\repos\Test.Web.Main\Test.Common.Image\ImageManager.cs:line
> 109 Feb 9 19:40:10 vmi1190349 dotnet-MyTest[9456]: at
> MyTest.Controllers.MyController.Get(ImageOptions MyPost) in
> C:\Users\TestUser\source\repos\Test.Web.Main\MyTest\Controllers\MyController.cs:line
> 84

**Additional Details**

I use SkiaSharp with text via SKTypeFace so I believe I need the SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux package. However, after trying other suggestions and those not working, I removed the package and installed SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies. I'm still receiving the error though. My application takes user input to determine how SkiaSharp is used so I'm not hitting any code that is using SKTypeFace and I'm still receiving the same error while using the NoDependencies package.

My project has references to the following packages:
[image]

I initially published the application with Target-Runtime = Portable but that didn't work. I tried moving the LibSkiaSharp.so file from the Runtimes directory to my web applications directory and that didn't work. I've also tried updating my publish settings to Target-Runtime=linux-x64 as this puts all of the project files in the root directory, redeployed, restarted the apache server and still receive the error.

Here are the file permissions for the deployed libSkiaSharp.so:
[image]

I've run the ldd command and it appears to have all of the necessary dependencies for libSkiaSharp.so.
[image]

I've also run the command to install libfontconfig1 as well

Answer (score 5):

I've had this exact issue on an AppService over a linux AppServicePlan in Azure and got solved by referencing the following NuGet package in the project `SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies`.

Once deployed running over an Ubuntu worked fine, while running locally on my Windows 11 never raised any issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a pretty similar issue. In my case the issue was the same message: dotnet can not find the libraries.

The nuget *NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies* is pretty helpful under controlled environments like dotnet docker's but outside of them can be a little headache and requires to maintainers to do some changes at the nuget package (for example, in [AWS environments](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/964)).

In the meanwhile... besides of libfontconfig1, did you try to install the missing libs libcdev, libexpat1, libuuid1, zlib1g and other references missing there by apt-installing?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I ended up just switching to a Windows Server for my VPS so that I could get the site up and running.  I currently don't have a way to go back and check to see if your suggestion will resolve it as the linux server I was initially using was deleted. If anyone else has this issue and can confirm that your suggestion resolves it then I will gladly mark this as the answer.  Many thanks for your response!